# Fetch data from Json

Tags: php, json, fetch

```
{"726":
{"id":"726","show":"1","level":"529","author":"1035","title":"a:3:
{s:3:\"geo\";s:24:\"Product name1\";s:3:\"eng\";s:24:\"Product 
name2\";s:3:\"rus\";s:24:\"Product name3\";}"
```

I need to get title where language is "geo".
So result should be: "Product name1"

I user code (81 is id):

```
$json_url = "http://some/sync.php?
products=1&hash=566gfjfhgkd4343";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE, 512, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$mytest2 = $data['81']['title'];
```

Comment: Ok, what's the question ?

Comment: With this script i get: a:3:{s:3:"geo";s:19:"iPhone 7 32GB Black";s:3:"eng";s:19:"iPhone 7 32GB Black";s:3:"rus";s:19:"iPhone 7 32GB Black";}

Comment: I need only fist title with "geo"

Comment: I want to get only: iPhone 7 32 GB Black

Comment: Please edit your question instead.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center. It's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: That's a serialized array. **If you trust the source**, you can unserialize it. I. e. `unserialize($data['81']['title'])['geo'];`. You should be sure about the trust, because unserializing malicious data is very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

i can't help to much cause your json is not valid, this is example to get value from json

```
$json = json_decode($response, true);
foreach($json['name'] as $key => $value)
{
  if(!empty($value['name']))
  {
   $name= $value['name'];
   $name= addslashes($name);
   $name= trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $name));
  }
  else
  {
    $name= '';
  }
   echo 'name= '.$name.'</br>';
}
```

Before you ask, please post your question clearly, so people can help you better.